# Prevent apt-get upgrade from using certain repos

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I've added the ubuntu base repo `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main` and a couple of PPAs into my debian installation to get access to some software that's not available on a debian repo. I've setup my apt preferences to be the following:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian,a=jessie
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian,a=wheezy
Pin-Priority: 990

Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu,a=vivid
Pin-Priority: 500

Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu,a=utopic
Pin-Priority: 400
```

However whenever I do `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` I get a whole bunch of ubuntu packages in there. Is there anyway to prevent that from happening? I just want the ubuntu repos for very select packages. I know I could just add the repos temporarily and then remove them and re-add them but that seems like a hassle. Are my priorities too high? Or is it something else?

The result of `apt-cache policy ffmpeg`:

```
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 6:0.8.17-1
Version table:
 7:2.4.3-1ubuntu1~utopic1 0
    400 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
 6:0.8.17-1 0
    990 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: If you only want certain packages, why not give high priority for these packages only? Anyway, what you see is that probably there are some other packages needed, that aren't in Debian repo - hence it decides to pull them, despite being low priority - because it simply decided that they are the only ones out there.

Comment: I didn't specify specific packages because won't I run into dependency issues doing that? And I figured that's what I was seeing but is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: May I ask what exactly are you trying to install?

Comment: @MatthewRock OBS, ffmpeg, and handbrake

Comment: Why Ubuntu? It looks like [handbrake is available for Debian](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/handbrake). Also, [here](http://superuser.com/questions/286675/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-debian) is post about ffmpeg on debian(but if you only need it for handbrake, you probably don't need it).

Comment: @MatthewRock XD...I guess I should go to the repos...their website only shows a ppa. And I need ffmpeg for OBS. Which to my knowledge is only available via a PPA or source and I feel like PPA is easier especially since I then get updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `apt-cache policy` with no arguments to see if the pinning preferences you set are having the effect you thought they would.

If that doesn't help, try running `apt-cache policy` with a package name which is unexpectedly being pulled from ubuntu. This should show you the available versions of that package, the scores it gets assigned, and it will mark (by way of a `***` marker) which package apt considers the 'best' option.

If that doesn't help you, post the output of the above two commands.

Comment: I don't see a `***` marker but I believe it's looking at the proper repo...I'll edit my original post with the result.

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken; what you need to look at is the candidate. The output says 'candidate: 6:0.8.17-1', so that part seems to work. If the ubuntu version still gets pulled in, that can only mean one of the packages you're upgrading has a dependency on the new version of ffmpeg, or a conflict against the old one. Try running `apt-get install` on the packages which apt wants to upgrade, until you see ffmpeg pulled in; you'll then know which of the packages or package sets has the dependency or conflict that causes it to happen. Run `apt-cache policy` on those packages, too.

Comment: So I installed ffmpeg and it came from the debian repos but it's the wrong ffmpeg. There's a certain dependency that comes with the ubuntu one but `apt` doesn't want to install it. It looks like it's going to have to update pulse and some other stuff to the ubuntu versions. Apparently the debian ones are versioned differently or something. When I try to install obs I get `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 obs-studio : Depends: libavdevice-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libfdk-aac0 (>= 0.1.1) but it is not installable`

Comment: I guess I should start a new question...my original question has been resolved. I figured out that I need to do `n=jessie` instead of `a=jessie` so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem is in your references to Debian repositories. Change the first two rules in your apt preferences to:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian,n=jessie
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian,n=wheezy
Pin-Priority: 990
```

This will cause apt-update to replace everything installed on your system with the version in jessie if availble (even if it is a downgrade). Packages not availble in jessie will prefer wheezy (or a specified target) over other availble repositories (assuming an upgrade from currently installed). I'm not sure if the archives in Ubuntu repositories are named with the codenames or if you also must change the "a=" to "n=" for those entries.

See the [apt preferences man page](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=5&query=apt_preferences&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en).